# What is happening when a struct is being passed as a parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI example:

```swift
    @State private var numbers: [Int] = []
    @State private var currentNumber = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                .onDelete(perform: removeRows) // #1
                }
                
                Button("Add Number") {
                    self.numbers.append(self.currentNumber)
                    self.currentNumber += 1
                }
            }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton()) // #2
        }
    }
    
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        numbers.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
```

I understand when a function `removeRows` (#1 in the example) is passed as a parameter, that's a closure that's to be executed later.

What is happening behind the scene when a struct like `EditButton()` (#2) is passed as a parameter? Is an instance being instantiated? A computed property being returned? A method being called?

Comment: I presume `EditButton` is a `View`? `EditButton()` creates an instance of type `EditButton`. That instance is passed as an argument. No magic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a line like

```
navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
```

...nothing happens "behind the scene".

The parentheses are an initializer, so the phrase `EditButton()` instantiates the EditButton struct. We now have an instance of that struct. The method call `navigationBarItems(leading:)` expects a parameter of a type that conforms to View, and the EditButton instance *is* that parameter (strictly speaking, the argument that is passed into the method call).

This is really no different from what happens when you say `print("howdy")`. You make a String struct instance whose value is `"howdy"` and you pass it as parameter to the `print` method call. Indeed, if anything has something going on "behind the scene", it is the String literal `"howdy"` — you should wonder how *that* works, if you're going to wonder at something.